# What is the biography of Rav Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern?

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures, biography

[Rav Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern](http://www.virtualgeula.com/yam/) is the Rosh Yeshiva of Toras Chochom in Israel. What is his background and biography? Meaning, where did he grow up, which yeshivot did he learn at and under whom (I know he was in Golders Green for some time)? I'm looking for as much biographic information as possible.

Comment: When I saw the title I thought you were referring to the Kotzker :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin apparently he is related

Comment: Where do you live and why are you curious to know?

Comment: @Yehoshua I live in the US and read his weekly emails so I'd like to know more about the person who comes up with such amazing torah. I always try to readthe biography of the people I learn from

Comment: See Joey Rosenfeld on r itche on YouTube by his intro video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%9F) he is a Chasid of Ger from birth. He learned in the Yeshivas of Lucerne and Gateshead. He is married to the daughter of R' Yosef Lubinsky from Antwerp (known as the Chantshin Rabbi). He moved to Yerushalayim after his marriage and learned with R' Eliezer Shlomo Schick and R' Nissan Dovid Kivak. He is also close to R' Tzvi Hirsh Rosenbaum (Kretchnifer Rabbi-Siget).